# Freewheel threading on Miche flip-flop hub

Tags: hub, freewheel, single-speed, sprocket

I'm currently building a parts list for a new single-speed bike. In the process, I came across a nice looking flip-flop hub from Miche: The ["Primato Pista/Strada"](https://www.miche.it/en/products/cat-pistard/mozzi/primato-pista-strada.html)

I figured that adding the fixed sprocket is best done using a dedicated Miche carrier. However, for the freewheel sprocket, I'm confused. I read about Italian, ISO and British threadings, all being approx. 35x24 tpi. On the referenced website though, it states that the freewheel is 36x24 tpi, which seems too large for regular freewheel sprockets. I couldn't find any suitable sprockets online.

Is it possible to just use regular Italian freewheel sprockets on that hub (as for the fixed sprocket)? If not, where can I find suitable freewheel sprockets?

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's just a mistake on their sheet and there are no 36x24 single speed freewheels.

Comment: I'm guessing they got the numbers backwards.  My understanding is that fixie cogs are often made with an "odd" thread so they won't be used on freewheel hubs.

Answer (score 4):

I have these hubs, I used a normal freewheel (1.37" x 24TPI) I had lying around from my old single speed build.

I'm 99% sure you also need a normal single speed / BMX / trials freehub. The 1% doubt I have is, that I don't know which model/year your hub is. And I don't know if they ever did a different one.

Worst come to worst, buy a freehub from a place which does refunds easily. That way, you can try to fit the freehub and if it doesn't fit, just get your money back.

Answer (score 1):

I built a pair of wheels with Miche Primato Strada/Pista with a Sturmey Archer freewheel SFS30.W190.CA0 (19 teeths, chain: 1/2" 1/8"). No problem for setting up the freewheel on the hub.